# Pass Custom array of Object as a Parameter in API Retrofit PUT Call

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I have to call an API to update the emergency contact of specific user.

```
https://stay-safe-api.azurewebsites.net/5eadd53761***0f6017/update/emergency_contact_details

//Body of API  
{
"EmergencyContacts": [
    {
        "FullName" : "Johon",
        "PhoneNumberCountryCode" : "ae",
        "PhoneNumberCountryDialCode" : "971",
        "PhoneNumber" : "5534566"

    }   
]
}
```

So I have an array which is I am passing in my API Call but whenever it's called, I got an error that inputs are incorrect.

I dont know what I am doing wrong I am actually new so can you guys help me out ?

APIInteface.class

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("update/emergency_contact_details")
Call<RegisterResponse> setEmergencyContact(@Field("EmergencyContacts[]") List<EmergencyList> 
EmergencyContacts);
```

APIClient.class

```
 public static Retrofit getClientEmerg(String id) {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://stay-safe-api.azurewebsites.net" + id + "/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClientEmerg(id).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<RegisterResponse> call = apiInterface.setEmergencyContact(emergencyLists);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response) {

         }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });


}
```

So let me know that what I am doing wrong in passing array as a param in API Call? Because I am getting error that "This is invalid request. Please make sure inputs are correct."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Body annotation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html) in your ApiInterface instead (and get rid of FormUrlEncoded):

```
@PUT("update/emergency_contact_details")
Call<RegisterResponse> setEmergencyContact(@Body List<EmergencyList> EmergencyContacts);
```

Still it's strange why you need to send contacts' list though it seemed that endpoint includes id in path (so you can update by this PUT just one contact)

Comment: Hey, Thankyou so much for your response. yes I have figured out the issue and you are right I used Body and i was missing @Headers({"Accept: application/json"}).